# iOS Web App problems with apple-mobile-web-app-capable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I am currently writing a small web app using Asp.net MVC and jQuery mobile.  Everything is rendering fine in the desktop test environment and in Safari browser on the iPad.  However, when I add `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` to the head I start getting some weird behaviors.

Here is the beginning of my simple test login page for the explanation below:

```
<%@ Page Title="Test App" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TestApp.ViewModels.LoginViewModel>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head runat="server"> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />  
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="../../../Content/Images/touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<!-- <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="../../../Content/Images/splash-screen-1024x748.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="../../../Content/Images/splash-screen-768x1004.png" /> -->
<title>Test App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="../../../Scripts/jquery.1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../../Content/jquery-mobile-fluid960.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" media="screen" href="../../../Content/mobile.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BlockMove(event) {
        // Tell Safari not to move the window
        event.preventDefault();
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body id="login" ontouchmove="BlockMove(event);">
```

At first Safari would crash every time I tried to load from the 'Home Screen' icon with apple-mobile-web-app-capable content="yes" but not with content="no" or when it was missing.  Through testing I found if I commented out the splash images Safari wouldn't crash but would load some weird code.  The safari chrome would be gone like it is supposed to but would only show this text in the body:

```
Test App function BlockMove(event) { // Tell Safari not to move the windowevent.preventDefault();} Mobile: Password:
```

This is strange because it is listing the page title and my javascript from the head as regular text in the body.  On top of that no javascript or CSS is being executed (or so it appears).  This behavior is odd because like I said earlier it runs perfectly fine in a normal iOS Safari browser or when apple-mobile-web-app-capable is missing or set to no.  I have some Safari crash logs I found but from what I understand not much I can do with those without source.

Any insight on why this could be happening would be greatly appreciated because I am at a loss.  I've been searching for days trying to find someone else with the same problem with no luck.  Hopefully it is something simple I am overlooking.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue. What I have been able to determine so far is that the user-agent string is different when accessing the web site normally and when it is accessed as an application.

When accessed as an application, the user-agent string is missing information that leads the page to be rendered as a browser ASP.NET does not recognize and with no capabilities, including javascript. This leads to the behavior you are seeing.

I found this one link that provides a solution, although I have not yet been able to get it to work for me.

http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/29/Gotcha-iPad-versus-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That is pretty interesting because all of my tests were pointing to that possibility.  I couldn't understand why it would render fine in regular safari but not from the home icon.  I will give that workaround a go later today.

Comment: One other interesting thing from some recent tests.  I could get the HTML elements coded in C# such as `<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoginID) %>` to finally display by changing the ContentType back to application/xhtml+html.  Once again this is only for when web-app-capable is present and set to yes.  Hopefully one or both of these can help solve this bizarre behavior.