# Jquery Mobile transition stops working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a JQM site and I'm having a very odd thing happen and I'm not sure what might be causing it.

The issue presents itself when I try to use one of the JQM data-transitions on a page that is loaded via ajax. My process is as follows. When a link is clicked I use Ajax to rewrite a container div so the data displayed is dynamic and I am using JQM to handle the transition.

Below is my code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function setContent(command,value,url,target){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        type: "post",
                        data: 'value='+value+'&command='+command,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $.mobile.loading('show');
                        },
                        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            console.log("sucess");
                            replaceHtml(target,response);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            console.log("error occured:"+textStatus, errorThrown);
                        },
                        complete: function(){
                            $.mobile.loading('hide'); //;
                            //$.mobile.changePage( "about/us.html", { transition: "flip"} );
                        }
                    });
                }

                function replaceHtml(object,html){
                    $(object).html();
                    $(object).html(html);
                }

                function checkhash(){
                    if ($('#loadedpage').html() == '') document.location.href = "#home";
                }

                //$(function(){
                $(document).live('pageinit', function(){

                    checkhash();

                    $(".navlink").live("click", function() {
                        var command = $(this).data("command");
                        var value = $(this).data("value");
                        var url= $(this).data("url");
                        var target = $(this).attr("href");
                        //alert(command+" "+value+" "+url+" "+target);
                        setContent(command,value,url,target);

                    });

                });
            </script>
```

When .navlink is clicked I ajax to process.php which returns html that is placed into the target div. The target div in this case is also the same link that JQM is trying to transition to. See example link below:

```
            <a href="#loadedpage" class="navlink rollover" data-transition="flip" data-command="query" data-value="colors" data-url="process.php">Pick a Color</a>
```

"#loadedpage" is the container div. Everything seems to be working properly aside from the fact that NONE of the transitions seem to be triggering. When I click the link the page just flashes and the new content is there. I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing and I've been searching the web all day trying to figure out what i did wrong.

I'm Using JQM 1.2.0 with JQuery 1.8.2

A weird effect is that when i first load the page all the transitions that are on the "#home" page seem to work... it's when I try try to click a link that was added to the page via ajax that the transitions fail. I believe that I am doing something wrong in the way I add new content to the DOM, in that maybe JQM can't initialize it properly?

Please help :D

EDIT:

Another thing I just noticed is that none of the JQM data attributes seem to be working when I load them via ajax. The code below is taken from my PHP script which I used to generate the content.

```
    function makeHeader(){
        return "<div id='menubar' data-position='fixed' data-role='header' data-tap-toggle='false'>
                    <table width='100%' cellspacing='0px' cellpadding='0px' border='0px'>
                        <tr><td width='12%'>
                                <a href='#home' data-transition='flip'>
                                    <img src='/images/menu_button.png'>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width='90%'>
                                <img src='/images/menu_bar.png'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>";
    }
```

"data-fixed" doesn't seem to be working at all, the header renders but it's not fixed it's just attached to the top of the page like any other element would be. I did a little searching and found that there is a way to force JQM to re-load elements by using .trigger('create'). This fixed the header but did not fix the transitions.

EDIT:

Still fighting with JQM. I've made a small change thinking maybe if I load the ajax fragment through JQM's changepage() method it might not ignore the transition. It still doesn't work :( ... I'm very confused as to what might be causing this.

CHANGE TO CODE:

```
            function specialsetContent(command,value,url,target,effect){
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "post",
                    data: 'value='+value+'&command='+command,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $.mobile.loading('show');
                    },
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        console.log("sucess");
                        replaceHtml(target,response);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log("error occured:"+textStatus, errorThrown);
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $.mobile.loading('hide'); //;
                        $.mobile.changePage(target,{transition:effect});
                    }
                });
            }
```

I added $.mobile.changePage() at the complete call for ajax.The content loads fine.. but still no transition effects.

Le Sigh

EDIT:

More testing and I've found out that $(document).on('pageinit', function(e) { alert("init");}); stops alerting after the first ajax call. I think this may have something to do with the issue I'm having.

Comment: is it happening really fast and the show hide is the flash you see?

Comment: You are using the correct `<!DOCTYPE html>`? And what browser are you using? JQM says, that if your browser does not support `CSS 3D transform`, you will only get `fade` (see [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-transitions.html).

Comment: And, are you using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`, which will break AJAX when you load your app on iOS from homescreen.

Comment: doc type is html 5  <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: and I am using that meta tag 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

this breaks ajax?

Comment: @TheSnooker: Yes. Wait, I try to dig out a link.

Comment: @TheSnooker: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322656/ios-web-app-problems-with-apple-mobile-web-app-capable) and [here](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/29/Gotcha-iPad-versus-ASPNET.aspx). 2nd link explains it nicely. I'm not sure this is really still a problem though. It is in Coldfusion, which I'm using, so I'm not using this meta tag.

Comment: @TheSnooker: data-attributes can't really "break", if your items don't get enhanced (is it?), you could try to call `trigger("create")` on the parent element, so if you add `<div.content>` try calling on that elements parent.

Comment: @frequent I've tried using the .trigger method and it does fix some of the appearance things. Like the data-fixed for the header and so forth but it doesn't effect the missing transitions.

Comment: @frequent I tried this is firefox 16, Safrai for windows I think version 3 something. IE9 and Chrome. I know some browsers don't support CSS transitions but none of them were working :-/. It's odd I've watched the console in firebug because I have debug lines all over the place now. It seems like for some reason the things loaded into the container div just don't work. None of the data- attributes that JQM uses work when I load them from a PHP script via ajax. It's really puzzling me what I could have done to break it.

Comment: hm. Not really sure... you could try to check on 'pagebeforechange' what the data object contains... hold up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on( "pagebeforechange", function( e, data ) {
   console.log( e )
   console.log( data )
});
```

This fires before anything happens on a `changePage`. The data object contains all changePage parameters, such as `fromPage`, `transition`, ...

Check what transition is.

Comment: I tried the log event and this was the output from it. I noticed it has a transistion but "allowSamePageTransistion is false. I'm not sure what that parameter does or if that might be the problem or not.



 allowSamePageTransition : false
 
changeHash : true
 
fromHashChange : false
 
fromPage : [div#loadedpage.ui-page]

 
link : [a.navlink #loadedpage]

 
pageContainer : [body.ui-mobile-viewport]

 
reverse : false

 
showLoadMsg : true

 
transition : "flip"

Comment: Also I noticed my fromPage and toPage are the same place. This makes sense since i'm just changing the content of that container but maybe I should be using different containers for everything? Right now every ajax response rewrites whats inside <div.loadedpage>. You know... I just had a thought.. maybe I'm clearing out the container before it has a chance to read whats in there?

Comment: OMG!.. lol that was it.. I was clearing out the contents of the div before JQM had a chance to read it. I feel like a noob. Once I setup a second container the transitions started working perfectly.. lol

So the solution: don't use the same container over and over.

Comment: ok. Glad it worked. Please check my answer if it helped you find the solution!

Comment: you're welcome! As a sidenote: you could also set `allowSamePageTransition` to true, which is what I'm sometimes doing when I need to reload a page with changing content. But better not touch yours now that is't working :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into this. The cause of my problem was the fact that I was using the same container over and over. What I think was happening was I was re-writing the contents of  too quickly and the data-attributes were being overwritten.

so I added a second container and everything started working fine :)

```
        <div id="loadedpage" class="ui-page" data-theme="none" data-role="page" data-url="loadedpage"></div>
        <div id="loadedpage1" class="ui-page" data-theme="none" data-role="page" data-url="loadedpage1"></div>
```

In short don't try to transition to the same page your on.. derp